# How to query table size, max size and row count in Progress OpenEdge Database

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I am connected to an OpenEdge Database using JDBC and I want to query information like table size, max size, and row count. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to query this sort of thing at runtime is to read the table and calculate what you need. It's not going to be that pleasant.

The best way to provide this sort of information though is to use a DB Analysis. 
From a proenv session on the database server:

> proutil [dbname] -C dbanalys > mydb.dbana

The output of this contains all the info that you need. 
You should be careful of running this during busy times as it will have a performance impact.

Documentation on the command is available here: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmadm%2Fproutil-dbanalys-qualifier.html%23wwID0EFCKY

This also includes details on the -csoutput option that produces the files in a nicely segregated text file format which may make parsing the info you want easier.

Comment: Is there a way to get this with Open Edge SQL?

Comment: I would really warn against it. Use the dbanalys output like I mentioned above.

Comment: Correct, but remember. You might not always have access to a proenv session.